# Canvas right click in Openseadragon

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, openseadragon

Is it possible canvas **right click** will work? I need to work on right click? When i click right mouse button, I need to show some popup. Is it possible? Then how?

Answer (score 6):

You want the `canvas-nonprimary-press` handler, like so:

```
viewer.addHandler('canvas-nonprimary-press', function(event) {
    if (event.button === 2) { // Right mouse
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
});
```

There is also a `canvas-nonprimary-release` if you need it. Reference:

http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.Viewer.html#event:canvas-nonprimary-press

If you want to disable the standard right-click menu, you can do something like this (assuming jQuery):

```
$(viewer.element).on('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It was very useful. Thanks u so much.